# packing imageView in ListView

Tags: android, image, listview

How can I pack an `ImageView` inside a custom View depending on image count?

let see this image

[image]

> image not shown I don't know the problem

first two images be larger but when image be more than 3 its size be smaller 
any idea how can I do it in custom View and add the View in `ListView`

my idea is to make and `LinearLayout` horizontal 
and add `ImageView` inside it with `Layout_weight`
but still have problem on it

Comment: create a custom view with the specifics

Comment: This can be done by creating a Custom View . Create a View by extending a Container(Any Layout or any Container). And  set the Image Urls to the View and validate the view at runtime as per image count.

Comment: @ADM any example ?

Comment: Well i haven't done it . But you can search for collage view android . This is pretty much close to your problem .

Comment: Are your image coming from web? If yes then, what you use to load your image?

Comment: @EnamulHaque yes from web and i use Picasso

Comment: Do you check your url? Check that in browser with that url. Like this url https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJx3a.png

Comment: @EnamulHaque  no its not problem in image Load i have problem in packing them as grid depend on image count like image i share in question

Comment: Do you using gridview  inside ListView for image? Then use     android:numColumns="auto_fit" in grid.

Comment: @EnamulHaque did grid a good idea for that or make an custom View extends LinearLayout or any thing else